# How to read multiple files using "getfileasync" method in UWP

Tags: c#, asynchronous, file-io, uwp

I am developing an UWP app and I need to read in some Json fils for data usage in assests folder.

Then I created this method,

```
public async Task<StorageFile> access(string filename)
    {
        var storageFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\data\" + filename);
        return storageFile;
    }

public async Task<string> read(StorageFile storagefile)
    {
        string content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storagefile);
        return content;
    }
```

Therefore, I used this method in `mainpage` to read a file first,

```
Task<StorageFile> stream1_1 = access("mycourse.json");
Task<string> stream1_2 = read(stream1_1.Result);
string mycourseinfo = stream1_2.Result;
```

**It comes out successful when I try to display it in a textblock**

```
mytextblock.text = mycourseinfo;
```

Then I added another one to read a second file

```
Task<StorageFile> stream2_1 = access("class_info.json");
Task<string> stream2_2 = read(stream2_1.Result);
string allclassinfo = stream2_2.Result;
```

**Then the problem came out, the app wont complie also showing no error message, I supposed it was a dealock.....**

I tried to read the second file alone and its successful again!
So how am I able to resolve this problem!! I need to read in three files!

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add await behind your methods because they are returning **Tasks**. when i add await behind it it will complete executing that line and only after completing it will move to the next code line, your deadlock is being created because you are not using await. use following code to read each file.

```
StorageFile stream1_1 = await access("mycourse.json");
string stream1_2 = read(stream1_1);
string mycourseinfo = stream1_2;
```

> also notice the return types should not be **Task** when using await.

in order to avoid making your constructor **async** you have to use the **Loaded** event.

So in constructor of your page add the following loaded event like this :

```
Loaded += async (s, e) =>
{
    //do any awaited stuff here
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Once I added `await` to it, the ide asked me to turn the main method to `async`. However, I am implementint this method when the page is loaded,  so it residise inside the `public mainpage`,  and then i face the prolem turning the mainpage method to async.....

Comment: you dont need the main constrcutor to be asyc, as you said u can just put it in the loaded event and make the loaded event asyc @Zizheng